# Hide AddressBar in IOS 6 safari

Tags: javascript, ios, ios6, safari

I am trying to hide the address bar in Safari in ios 6, but it hides partially, in portrait mode. It hides fine in landscape mode. I am using window.scrollTo(1, 1). Also, the problem happens to be on a specific device with a different version of Safari than on another device. Is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the address bar

```
<!-- fullscreen -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<!-- status bar style -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

but it did not work in all iOS versions

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not working please suggest something else